# SQL ORDER BY / Sort Php

Tags: php

I am struggling with my php and would love some assistance in the right direction. Here is my code so far:

```
    <?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("rsi", $connection) or die(mysql_error());

    $query = "SELECT * FROM events"; 
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("error in query"); 

if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
    echo "<table border=1></tr>" .
        "<th>ID</th>" .
        "<th>Name</th>" .
        "<th>Date</th>" .
        "<th>Location</th>" ;

while ($row = @ mysql_fetch_array($result)){
             print "<tr>";
             print "<td>".$row['id']."</td>"; 
             print "<td>".$row['name']."</td>"; 
             print "<td>".$row['date']."</td>"; 
             print "<td>".$row['location']."</td>"; 
             print "</tr>"; 
}
print "</table>";
}


?>
```

I am now hoping to order the results from the database by clicking on each/any of the headers (for example date). Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

To order the result you use [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html).

Here's an example to order by id:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id";
```

To get it to order when you click on a header you need to make it execute the new query in some way. How to do that I leave out for you to find. Typically you reload the whole page with a parameter on what to sort on or use ajax, which would let you update contents on the page without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the order by column name and order ascending or decending by either GET or POST.
Here is an example of GET.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM events"; 
if(isset($_GET['sort'])
{
    $query.= ' order by '.mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sort']).' '.mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['order']);
}
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("error in query"); 


while ($row = @ mysql_fetch_array($result)){
       print "<tr>";
       print "<td>".$row['id']."</td>"; 
       print "<td>".$row['name']."</td>"; 
       print "<td><a href='http://www.domain.com/currentpageurl?sort=date&order=asc'>".$row['date']."</td>"; 
       print "<td>".$row['location']."</td>"; 
       print "</tr>"; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Shakti's answer, I would recommend not using $_GET directly in the query. I would run your $_GET through some sort of sanity check and only allow specific values, otherwise you are leaving your site open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to sort the table in the browser. You probably don't want to keep querying your database for the same information just in a different sort order. Something like this perhaps: http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo

To use tablesorter:

1. Change one line of your code to:

> ```
> echo "<table border=1 id="myTable" class="tablesorter"><tr>"
> ."<th>ID</th>" ."<th>Name</th>" ."<th>Date</th>"
> ."<th>Location</th></tr>" ;
> ```

2. Add this line at the end of the body:

> ```
> <script>
>     $(document).ready(function() 
>         { 
>             $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
>         } 
>     ); 
> </script>
> ```

3. If you don't already have jquery, include it in the `<Head>` section:

> ```
> <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> ```

4. Download jquery.tablesorter.js from http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.zip
5. Include the file jquery.tablesorter.js like this:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
> ```