# PHP/MYSQL: How to order a list of items clicking a link

Tags: php, mysql, switch-statement

I´m doing an excercise of getting a list of products from an sql database (without using objects).
I´ve got it right, but now I would like to add the possibility to order the results in asc or desc orden according to the user´s clicks in tiny up and down arrows that I´ve placed beside each table header.

This is my original code:

```
<?php
@$link=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','phpdb')
OR die('No se pudo conectar a la base');
$sql='SELECT p.cod_producto,
        p.nombre,
        p.precio,
        p.stock,
        p.cod_categoria,
        c.descripcion,
        p.cod_marca,
        m.nombre_marca
FROM    productos p JOIN categorias c, marcas m
WHERE   p.cod_categoria=c.cod_categoria
AND     p.cod_marca=m.cod_marca';

@$rs=mysqli_query($link,$sql)
OR die('No se puede ejecutar la consulta a la base');
?>

<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Cod. Producto</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Precio</th> 
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Cod. Categoría</th>
        <th>Descripción</th>
        <th>Cod. Marca</th>
        <th>Nombre Marca</th>
    </tr>
<?php
$linea=1;

while($v=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
    if($linea%2==1) $color='#ccccff';
    else $color='#ffffff';
?>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="<?php echo $color; ?>"><?php echo $v['cod_producto'];  ?></td>
        <td bgcolor="<?php echo $color; ?>"><?php echo $v['nombre'];  ?></td>
        <td bgcolor="<?php echo $color; ?>"><?php echo $v['precio'];  ?></td>
        <td bgcolor="<?php echo $color; ?>"><?php echo $v['stock'];  ?></td>
        <td bgcolor="<?php echo $color; ?>"><?php echo $v['cod_categoria'];  ?></td>
        <td bgcolor="<?php echo $color; ?>"><?php echo $v['descripcion'];  ?></td>
        <td bgcolor="<?php echo $color; ?>"><?php echo $v['cod_marca'];  ?></td>
        <td bgcolor="<?php echo $color; ?>"><?php echo $v['nombre_marca'];  ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
    $linea++;
    }
?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='<?php echo mysqli_num_fields($rs);?>' align="center">
        Registros: <?php echo mysqli_num_rows($rs);?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
</table>
```

Now, in order to do that, I thought on using **switch** statements, but this didn´t worked (I think I should use $_GET or $_POST, but don´t know how to use it here, I also thing that I shouldn´t copy the entire query again...) I tried this changes, without luck:

```
<?php
@$link=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','phpdb')
OR die('No se pudo conectar a la base');

$sql='SELECT p.cod_producto,
        p.nombre,
        p.precio,
        p.stock,
        p.cod_categoria,
        c.descripcion,
        p.cod_marca,
        m.nombre_marca
FROM    productos p JOIN categorias c, marcas m
WHERE   p.cod_categoria=c.cod_categoria
AND     p.cod_marca=m.cod_marca';

switch ($sql) {
    case 'codProdUp':
        'SELECT p.cod_producto,
        p.nombre,
        p.precio,
        p.stock,
        p.cod_categoria,
        c.descripcion,
        p.cod_marca,
        m.nombre_marca
        FROM    productos p JOIN categorias c, marcas m
        WHERE   p.cod_categoria=c.cod_categoria
        AND     p.cod_marca=m.cod_marca
        ORDER BY p.cod_producto ASC ';
        break;
    case 'codProdDown':
        'SELECT p.cod_producto,
        p.nombre,
        p.precio,
        p.stock,
        p.cod_categoria,
        c.descripcion,
        p.cod_marca,
        m.nombre_marca
        FROM    productos p JOIN categorias c, marcas m
        WHERE   p.cod_categoria=c.cod_categoria
        AND     p.cod_marca=m.cod_marca
        ORDER BY p.cod_producto DESC ';
        break;      
}
```

Please note that I´ve read [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861242/sql-order-by-sort-php) that suggest using **isset()**, but didn´t understand how to replicate it here. I also think that using switch could be easier...

Comment: So, it's the same resut set each time, just oredered differently? You should handle that logic at the application level - a bit of ajax could do that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now this is your base query

```
$sql='SELECT p.cod_producto,
    p.nombre,
    p.precio,
    p.stock,
    p.cod_categoria,
    c.descripcion,
    p.cod_marca,
    m.nombre_marca
FROM    productos p JOIN categorias c, marcas m
WHERE   p.cod_categoria=c.cod_categoria
AND     p.cod_marca=m.cod_marca ';
```

We need extra space at the end of $sql or we need to put it there everytime.

Now if we want to add order by, we can just add it to end of that string. So:

```
$sql .= 'ORDER BY p.cod_producto ASC';
```

Now that we have multiple order by conditions something like this might work

```
switch($_GET['sort']){
    case "codProdUp": 
        $sql .= 'ORDER BY p.cod_producto ASC';
        break;
    case "codProdDown":
        $sql .= 'ORDER BY p.cod_producto DESC';
        break;
}
```

Now your $sql would contain base + conditional order by at the end.

Now if you query www.example.com/site.php?sort=codProdUp or www.example.com/site.php?sort=codProdDown the table would be sorted in different order.

This

```
$sql .= "ORDER BY";
```

is same thing as

```
$sql = $sql . "ORDER BY";
```